# Add class when using getElementById

Tags: javascript

I have an element which I need to hide after a few seconds but this element only needs to be hidden in this particular instance so I am trying to add an `Id` to the element. Problem is that my JS is only applying CSS class to the element if I `getElementsByClassName`.

**The element:**

```
<div id="main-messages" class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
```

**The JS:**

```
var m = document.getElementById("main-messages");

setTimeout(function(){
   if (m && m.length) {
       m[0].classList.add('hide');
   }
}, 3000);
```

**The CSS:**

```
.alert {
    positition: relative;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transform: translateX(0px);
    transition: .5s ease-out
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.alert.hide {
  visibility: hidden !important;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(0px);
  transition: visibility 0s 2s, opacity 2s linear;
}
```

I have also tried to create the CSS element by Id and add the `.hide` class to it but that did not work.. e.g. `#main-messages.hide{`

Comment: getElementById returns one element so you need to use `setTimeout(function(){m.classList.add('hide');},3000);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementById` returns a single element, but not nodeList.

In your code, `m.length` is always undefined (false), and `m[0]` as well. You must add class to a single element, without index:

```js
var m = document.getElementById("main-messages");

setTimeout(function() {
  if (m) {
    m.classList.add('hide');
  }
}, 3000);
```

```css
.alert.hide::after {
  content: "I'm hidden... really!";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-messages" class="alert">test... </div>
```

P.s. typo `.alert {positition` → position *)

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById() only returns one element not an array.

If you change this

```
  if (m && m.length) {
       m[0].classList.add('hide');
   }
```

to

```
m.classList.add("hide");
```

does it work then?

Answer (score 0):

It may help.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("main-messages").style.display = "none";
}, 3000);
})
```

```html
<div id="main-messages" class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">Hiiiii</div>
```